# Get a specific array element using Projection of MongoDB .Net Driver

Tags: .net, mongodb, projection

I have some classes.

```
public class MyClass
{
  public string Id {get;set;}
  public List<MyElement> MyList {get;set;} = new List<MyElement>();

  //Other extra fields
}
public class MyElement
{
  public string Text {get;set;}
  public string AnotherField {get;set;}
}
```

Here is my sample document of MyClass:

```
{
  "_id": "1",
  "MyList": [{
    "text":"Element 0"
  },{
    "text":"Element 1"
  }]
}
```

Now I want to retrieve only Element 0. I wrote the following code using Projection:

```
Expression<Func<MyClass, MyElement>> getElementZero = (c => c.MyList[0]);
Expression<Func<MyClass, List<MyElement>>> getList = (c => c.MyList);
FilterDefinition<MyClass> filter = Builders<MyClass>.Filter.Eq(p => p.Id, "1");
//This is good
List<MyElement> myList = mongoCollection.Find(filter).Project(getList).First();

//However, myElement is null after this projection
MyElement myElement = mongoCollection.Find(filter).Project(getElementZero).First();
```

Anybody know why? And how can I get a specific array element using the index of that element?

Update:

I did some experiment, and find out the following things:

1. If only the first element of an array is wanted, the following will work.

   ```
   //this will work
   MyElement myElement = mongoCollection.Find(filter).Project(c => c.MyList.First()).First();
   //this is not going to work
   MyElement myElement = mongoCollection.Find(filter).Project(c => c.MyList.GetElementAt(0)).First();
   ```
2. If I explicitly write a function, it will work:

   ```
   public MyElement GetElementAt(MyClass c, int index)
   {
     return c.MyList[index];
   }
   //this will work
   MyElement myElement = mongoCollection.Find(filter).Project(c => GetElementAt(c, someIndex)).First();
   ```

Comment: Maybe `Builders<yourclass>.Projection.ElemMatch(...)` will do what you're looking for? Or if you _only_ want the first one, `Builders<yourclass>.Projection.Slice(...)`

Comment: Yeah, Slice will work, but I test it, it will return other fields of MyClass as well.

Answer (score 0):

In Mongodb console(javaScript), you can achieve this using:

```
db.foo.find({_id:"1"}).map(function(u){return u.MyList[0].text})
```

You can try converting this in C# there must be some functions.

Comment: See my updates. I found a way to make it work by writing an explicit function. What I don't understand is that I think the lambda expression should be pretty much the same as writing a function.